# Unable to get values in google Material bar chart Dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova, google-visualization

HI here i am displaying charts using dynamic data and previously i got an error **Uncaught TypeError: google.charts.Bar ** some how i resolved it later the chart is displayed but it is displaying only null values.
[image]

Below is my Json data which i m getting dynamically

`[
  {
    "Amt": 92327.34,
    "Persons": 76,
    "Tax": 5768.0999999999995,
    "TransactionType": "ONLINE",
    "Transactions": 39
  }
]'

Below is my js code

```
google.charts.load('current', { 'packages': ['bar'] });
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(barCharttest);

function barCharttest() {
    var sess = dynamic.Session.getInstance().get();
    var ex = document.getElementById("dpdda");
    var clOptions = ex.options[ex.selectedIndex].value;
    var clOptions1 = ex.options[ex.selectedIndex].text;

    var d = new Date();
    d.setDate(d.getDate() - 1);
    var curr_date = d.getDate() - 1;
    var curr_month = d.getMonth() + 1;
    var curr_year = d.getFullYear();


    var dtf = document.getElementById("frm_sale_date").value;
    var dtt = document.getElementById("to_sale_date").value;

    var link2 = "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx/xxxxxxx/service1.svc/chart";

    var jsonData = $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: link2,
        data: "id=" + clOptions + "&cId_=" + sess.Id + "&Name_=" + clOptions1 + "&MachineId_=0&sId_=0&frmDate_=" + dtf + "&toDate_=" + dtt + "",
        dataType: 'json',

    }).done(function (results) {


        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'TransactionType');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Transactions');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Tax');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Amt');
        data.addRows(results.length);
        for (i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            data.setValue(i, 0, results[i]["TransactionType"]);
            data.setValue(i, 1, parseInt(results[i]["Transactions"]));
            data.setValue(i, 2, parseFloat(results[i]["Tax"]));
            data.setValue(i, 3, parseFloat(results[i]["Amt"]));
        }

        var options = {
            chart: {
                title: 'Company Performance',
                subtitle: 'Sales, Expenses, and Profit: 2014-2017',
            },
            bars: 'horizontal' // Required for Material Bar Charts.
        };

        var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('barchart_material'));


        chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));



    }
    );

}
```

below is my html code

```
    `<input type="date" id="frm_date"/>`

 `<input type="date" id="to_date"/>`
` <input type="button"  value="Click me" onclick="barCharttest()"/>`
`<div id="barchart_material" style="width:100%; height: 220px;overflow:scroll"></div>`
```

Answer (score 0):

i'm thinking the ajax call is not returning any data

if i use the json data provided in the question,
the chart draws fine

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', { 'packages': ['bar'] });
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(barCharttest);

function barCharttest() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'TransactionType');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Transactions');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Tax');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Amt');

  var results = [ { "Amt": 92327.34, "Persons": 76, "Tax": 5768.0999999999995, "TransactionType": "ONLINE", "Transactions": 39 } ];
  data.addRows(results.length);
  for (i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      data.setValue(i, 0, results[i]["TransactionType"]);
      data.setValue(i, 1, parseInt(results[i]["Transactions"]));
      data.setValue(i, 2, parseFloat(results[i]["Tax"]));
      data.setValue(i, 3, parseFloat(results[i]["Amt"]));
  }

  var options = {
      chart: {
          title: 'Company Performance',
          subtitle: 'Sales, Expenses, and Profit: 2014-2017',
      },
      bars: 'horizontal' // Required for Material Bar Charts.
  };

  var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('barchart_material'));
  chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="barchart_material"></div>
```

---

however, if i draw the chart using an empty array,
i get the same null results as seen in the posted image

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', { 'packages': ['bar'] });
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(barCharttest);

function barCharttest() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'TransactionType');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Transactions');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Tax');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Amt');

  var results = [  ];
  data.addRows(results.length);
  for (i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      data.setValue(i, 0, results[i]["TransactionType"]);
      data.setValue(i, 1, parseInt(results[i]["Transactions"]));
      data.setValue(i, 2, parseFloat(results[i]["Tax"]));
      data.setValue(i, 3, parseFloat(results[i]["Amt"]));
  }

  var options = {
      chart: {
          title: 'Company Performance',
          subtitle: 'Sales, Expenses, and Profit: 2014-2017',
      },
      bars: 'horizontal' // Required for Material Bar Charts.
  };

  var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('barchart_material'));
  chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="barchart_material"></div>
```

---

check the date clause used in the service providing the data

if you are using the from / to dates as actual date values,
and the same date is used for both parameters,
need to adjust the time portion to include at least 24 hours

meaning the *from* date should have a time of zero,
and the *to* date should have `23:59:59`

e.g., adjust parameters to include time...

from: `2017-05-29 00:00:00`
to:  `2017-05-29 23:59:59`

Comment: It is all fine with date clause and with date clause it worked for the pie chart

Comment: please share a sample of the data when the chart displays null --> `console.log(JSON.stringify(results));`

Comment: it is just [] or null

Comment: that's why the chart is showing null, the service isn't returning any data -- maybe double check the parameters passed as `data:` in the ajax call -- just before ajax look at --> `console.log("id=" + clOptions + "&cId_=" + sess.Id + "&Name_=" + clOptions1 + "&MachineId_=0&sId_=0&frmDate_=" + dtf + "&toDate_=" + dtt + "");`